# Spark Streaming Data to S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I'm building data lake in S3. Hence, I would like to store the raw data stream into s3 and below is my code snippet, where I have tried with local storage.

```
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
val engtweets = tweets.filter(status => status.getLang() == "en").map(x => x.getText())
  import sql.implicits._
engtweets.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    val df = rdd.toDF()
    df.write.format("json").save("../Ramesh")
 }
```

I would like to store Raw data(entire JSON object) in s3.

Answer (score 1):

Just setup the access key and secret key in core-site.xml as follows:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value>...</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value>...</value>
</property>
```

Once you have done this, you should be able to write into s3 using s3 protocol like : s3a:///

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `saveAsTextFile` method with path prefixed as

```
s3a://<file path>
```

required, your Amazon s3 is set-up correctly with or without credential.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_s3.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Im able to store the data locally. Since data is streamed, I would like to store the data in firehose and push it to S3. Hence, I wrote a method in Java for storing into kinesis firehose and it is working fine. However, I'm unable to get the strings from Dstreams.      
      val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
    val engtweets = tweets.filter(status => status.getLang() == "en")
    val statuses = engtweets.map(engtweets => engtweets.toString())               statuses.map(record => record.getBytes().toString()).print()